# Wordpress Feed URL redirecting to Login Page

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed, rss2

I am trying to read wordpress feed url into php

This is link of
[Wordpress Feed URL](https://intranet.saniservice.com/feed/rss2)

When we click on this url it redirects to login page where as it should have shown the contents of feed.

Below is my php code to read this feed url

```
<?php 

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xmlDoc->loadHTMLFile("https://intranet.saniservice.com/feed/rss2");
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

print_r($xmlDoc);

?>
```

When this code is executed it returns data but that data is of login page which we see when we click on feed url, I am not sure how can i stop this feed from redirecting to login page.

[image]

Comment: is this your website ?

Comment: This is not my website but I can tell admin if there are some changes that needs to be done in wordpress website .

Comment: well it maybe they only allow registered user to access their website content / feed

Comment: I am building webapp for admin where i need to read rss feed from wordpress website, I consulted with admin even he is unable to figure it out why it is redirecting to login page

Comment: I see (test) some links on that website.. all of them are redirected to the same page. so in this case it 's noylt just for feed page  only.

Comment: similar question, i think it does not work with authentication activated https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/181516